# How to parse a simple search query with PHP?

Tags: php, query-parser

So I like to have a simple (custom) search query. That exists of two things a PASSWORD and a DATE. So I can construct something like: `DATE BEFORE "01-11-2022 14:00" AND (PASSWORD IS "welcome" OR PASSWORD IS "1234")`.

My thoughts about parsing this is first getting an array like:

```
[
    {
        Condition: "DATE BEFORE \"01-11-2022 14:00\"",
        Operator: "AND"
    },
    [
        {
            Condition: "PASSWORD IS \"welcome\"",
            Operator: "OR"
        },
        {
            Condition: "PASSWORD IS \"1234\""
        }
    ]
]
```

Then walk through the conditions and parse them separatly by using `eval`.

```
$condition = str_replace('PASSWORD', $_GET['PASSWORD'], $condition);
$condition = str_replace('IS NOT', '!=', $condition);
$condition = str_replace('IS', '=', $condition);
$result = eval($condition);
```

1. If the condition has no operator; STOP
2. If the result is FALSE and the operator is AND; STOP
3. Else continue evaluating the next condition.

So if the password is 1234 and date is before this would result in.

```
[
    TRUE (AND)
    [
        FALSE (OR)
        TRUE
    ]
]
----
[
    TRUE (AND)
    TRUE
]
----
TRUE
```

But I am already stuck at parsing the search string, because the parentheses can be nested like `((PASSWORD IS "welcome" OR PASSWORD IS "1234") AND DATE BEFORE "01-11-2022") OR PASSWORD = "admin"`.

So hence the question. How can you parse this simple search query?

Comment: Read up on recursive patterns: https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php ...and for the love of god, don't use eval here, unless this is a little pet project - use a dispatch table to call functions for DATE, BEFORE, PASSWORD, ISNOT and IS...

Comment: I am reading it right now, thanks for the lead.

Comment: Something like [Symfony Expression Language](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html) might be useful if you don't want to implement a full parsing algorithm yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not formulate the conditions in a PHP-compliant way? Approach:

```
$query = 'DATE < "2022-11-01 14:00" AND (PASSWORD == "welcome" OR PASSWORD == "1234")';

$query = str_replace(['DATE','PASSWORD'],['"2022-10-31 13:00"','"1234"'],$query);
$isOk = eval('return '.$query.';');
var_dump($isOk);
```

Since eval() is dangerous, the replacements for DATE and PASSWORD must be checked carefully.

Comment: Omg... that is brilliant. I haven't thought about that.